# In SecItemCopyMatching the &keyRef returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, ios8, ios9

i have been using 
https://github.com/ideawu/Objective-C-RSA/blob/master/RSA.m
for the RSA encryption but in iOS 9 the kefRef is returned nil,works fine with iOS 8.What change should be made?

```
    SecKeyRef keyRef = nil;
    status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)privateKey,(CFTypeRef *)&keyRef);
    if(status != noErr){
    return nil;
    }
    return keyRef;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the public key used.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15129